# Does there exist an analog of "And show me the page" of cucumber?

Tags: rspec, cucumber

I want to see html page during run of some view spec.

If I run Cucumber, I can use "And show me the page" for such purposes. Is it possible for Rspec?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use of the capybara and launchy gems and then use `save_and_open_page` as described in this [post](http://techiferous.com/2010/04/using-capybara-in-rails-3/).

Comment: It gives `undefined local variable or method `save_and_open_page'`, what am I missing?

Comment: I had to add Launchy to my Gemfile, not just manually install it, to get it to work.  Maybe you can make sure you don't need to do that.